# GetTickCount64 call when upgrading to .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I have been forced to upgrade from VS2008 to VS2012. This means that all of my code needed to be updated to .NET Framework 4.0. My goal is to keep compatibility with Windows XP with this update.

So I have a solution with multiple projects. Most are written in VB. One project is written in C++ because I needed to make unmanaged calls to DDE commands and wrap that around a managed object. The best I could do was to compile that in the VS2008 environment with .NET 3.5 so that it would work in Windows XP without issues. My main project is now a mixed mode assembly. This is all probably superfluous information, but I state this just in case it is pertinent.

The compiled program works just fine on my Windows 7 development machine. When I test it out on a Windows XP machine, about 20% of the time the program is executed I get the error: "GetTickCount64 could not be located." I know that Windows XP does not support this call. The main problem is that there is no point in my software where I need to know how long it has been since the last boot. I assume that when it was compiled, something extra was added by Visual Studio. The software works fine after clicking "OK" on that message. It is just annoying to have. Is there any way to find where this call is being made and kill it? I have tried doing a search through the solution for "GetTickCount64" but have found nothing.

Comment: Can you catch the exception and output the stack trace?

Comment: "I have been forced to upgrade from VS2008 to VS2012. This means that all of my code needed to be updated to .NET Framework 4.0." You may have been forced to update to targeting the .NET Framework 4.0, but it was not a direct result of updating to VS 2012. VS2012 supports targeting .NET 2.0 (VS2005 default) or .NET 3.5 (VS2008 default) just fine.

Comment: Jim, I don't know if there is an exception to catch. It just shows a message box and blocks the current process until you click OK.  Z80Z28, you raise a good point. I did try to downgrade to framework 3.5, but then I was having issues referencing the older version of DataVisualization controls that I am using. I'm sure that I can figure it out if I compare/merge from older versions in my svn.

Comment: I tried downgrading everything to Framework 3.5, but I get indirect dependency to 4.0 errors. It seems to me that compiling in VS2012 still leaves dependencies to 4.0 even though I select 3.5 in my VC++ project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be experiencing issues related to the Windows XP Targeting for C++ in Visual Studio 2012. Support for Windows XP with C++ targets was added in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1, but must still be explicitly selected in your project properties.

[Windows XP Targeting with C++ in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx)

Comment: I do not see this option in my toolset even though I do have the update installed. Let me look into this.

Comment: I had to repair my update installation to get this selection. Once I set this for my VC++ projects, the error went away on the XP test machine. Thanks for your help :)